# QLabel & QComboBox setFont does NOT work

Tags: c++, qt, stylesheet, qcombobox, qlabel

I'm using `Qt` Framework to build an App supporting multiple languages.
The default font is loaded from `StyleSheet`.

I override `paintEvent()` method, and `setFont()` method works OK for all widgets except for `QLabel` and `QComboBox`.

For `QComboBox`, the selected item has the correct font, the but the dropdown list items are using the  default font. The `Qt` manual says `setFont` will set the font for both the `comboBox` button and the `comboBox` popup list to font.

Anyone happens to see this problem and have an idea to fix that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is so long, because I wrote different approaches, choose the best for you.

Try to do next:

Create `QListView`, customize it (with stylesheet for example)

Set model with your data and set view to `QComboBox` with special methods:

`setModel()` and `setView()`

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#setView

```
setStyleSheet("font-family: Arial;font-style: normal;font-size: 12pt");
```

For label you can use stylesheet too, setFont or just set HTML code with suitable font:

```
  QFont f( "Arial", 14, QFont::Bold);
  label->setFont(f);
```

With ComboBox you can use this for example:

```
QStringList stringList;
stringList << "#hello" << "#quit" << "#bye";
QStringListModel *mdl = new QStringListModel(stringList);

QFont comboFont("Arial",16,-1,true);
QListView *vw = new QListView;
vw->setFont(comboFont);

ui->comboBox->setModel(mdl);
ui->comboBox->setView(vw);
```

But it will install font to your data in popup menu, not in the header, so you can use also next:

```
QFont comboFont("Arial",16,-1,true);
for(int i = 0; i< ui->comboBox->count(); i++)
{
    ui->comboBox->setItemData(i,QVariant(comboFont),Qt::FontRole);
}
ui->comboBox->setFont(comboFont);
```

Wityh this code snippet you'll get popup menu and header with this font and you don't need create models and views.

Answer (score 0):

My dear, it is enough to do hereunder:

```
ui->CboxOpisBaza->lineEdit()->setFont(QFont("MS Shell Dlg 2", 12));
```